# ASP.NET MVC How to Set a controller in a Area as a Default controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a area in my application along with default MVC Controllers folder,
here is how my project structure looks.

[image]

I want to access controllers from my area without any prefix eg .

> localhost/Home --> should point to my HomeController in Men Area,
>
> localhost/Footware-->should point to my FootwareController in Men Area

And In my default controllers folder i have Controllers with same name as controllers in Men area, so i want access default controllers with 
Store prefix
eg:

> localhost/store/Home --> should pick HomeController from default
>   controllers page.
>
> localhost/store/Jeans --> should pick JeansControllers from default
>   controllers page.

route config in my area is:

```
public class MenAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Men";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Men_default",
                "Men/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

route config for application is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Global.asax.cs is

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }
```

regards,

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just create a Store area for those 2 store routes, and then just make a home and footware controller in the main webapp and not inside an area?

Comment: @Glitch100 there is so much code already developed and making any change to that will break app, and what i showed here is just a skeleton code not complete representation of my app.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, `.MapRoute` doesn't allow you to specify an area *However it is possible to alter the DataTokens in MVC6 *, otherwise it would be super easy, however the route that is returned can be altered to have the area.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ).DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "Men" });
```

*It is possible to alter the DataTokens in MVC6*

Also you need to make sure to register your areas first, so don't change the order of your `Application_Start` in the `Global.ascx.cs`. This needs to be first:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

An alternative is to override the View Engine which I have seen in an answer somewhere but looks a bit complicated.

**Similar Question:**
[ASP.NET MVC How to Set a controller in a Area as a Default controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479555/asp-net-mvc-how-to-set-a-controller-in-a-area-as-a-default-controller/32482585)

---

**Further Reading**

[Walkthrough: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#route-areas)

[The Magic of MVC Routing with multiple Areas](http://piranhacms.org/the-magic-of-mvc-routing-with-multiple-areas)

Comment: FYI, in MVC 6 you can now set `DataTokens` when setting up routing without having to resort to such measures.